# Switch fixed element to relative just before footer appears

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element `position:fixed` at the bottom of the window that I've called `.fixed_footer`. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="fixed_footer">Hello World</div>
<footer>Footer stuff</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed_footer {
    position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 70px;
    background: blue;
}
footer {
    width: 100%; height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

The footer has a normal relative position in the document.

What I want is for `.fixed_footer` to switch from `position: fixed` to `position: relative` just before the actual `footer` appears in the viewport, so that it fits nicely on top.

I've almost got it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var footer_off = $('footer').offset().top;
    var window_h = $(window).height();
    var transition_point = footer_off - window_h;

    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();

    if ( fixed_footer && scroll_top >= transition_point ) {
        fixed_footer = false;
        $('.fixed_footer').css({ 'position':'relative' });
    }
});
```

So basically, I start by figuring the `offset().top` of the actual `footer`.

To figure out the transition point (the point where the `fixed_footer` goes from fixed to relative) I subtract the window height from the footer offset, so that if I've scrolled past the transition point, I switch to relative.

It's nearly working but for some reason, it switches to fixed position a bit too early, it jumps out of sight briefly until you scroll down some more.

I'm wondering if the culprit is not `var window_h = $(window).height();` that is slightly offset from the actual viewport height.

[JSFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexkaskasoli/gzLm579t/)

Comment: Fiddle with us please

Comment: Include the jQuery library, you can find it on top left corner..

Comment: Moreover, you haven't specified the `fixed_footer` variable.

Comment: @user26409021 My bad, Fiddle is uploaded! (with that bool, sorry forgot to put it here, it's not that important at this point though it's just true)

Comment: @Juicy here's a start for you. You need to incorporate the height of the fixed footer element when calculating your transition point. http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/gzLm579t/1/

Comment: @scrowler Thanks I actually got that far though but as you say it's only a start. There is still an offset. The fixed footer jumps instead of sitting smoothly. I don't get this problem with my fixed header though and I really suspect it's something to do with the viewport height from window.height not being accurate.

Comment: @scrowler Using some absolute positioning and setting the offset, instead of relative, did the trick! Thanks for your help.